# Excel, desktop version. Automatically update data between tabs in dynamic enviroment

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: AAPL-V Tab][Investment Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9klfI.jpg)Overview:

1. Investment Summary tab is where I can get an overview and will do routine updates, instead of having to go to each tab.  The tabs are to record actions.
2. Each stock tab will be a combination of stock symbol and account.
3. The MSTR tab (basically the same as AAPL-V with no data and Symbol field, E1, shows "Select" and Name is blank) will get copied and renamed (manually) for each new stock, but I need formulas that will work dynamic between the tabs (worksheets). I don't want to have to write them for each stock added.

Notes:

1. The tab AAPL-V is the most up-to-date tab.
2. More stocks will be added over time to Investment Summary and sorted by symbol.
3. The data here is minimized for simplicity.

I need help with 2 things.

1. On APPL-V tab, cell A3 (Date Updated) a way to get the date from Investment Summary for the Symbol listed at the top.   Every time it is updated on Investment Summary, it should automatically update.  When the MSTR tab is copied and renamed for a new stock, and the symbol is listed at the top, the date should work because the stock symbol is the tab name and listed on both the Investment Summary tab and the stock tab.  A single date can't be used, as it is very likely that all the stocks will not be undated at the same time.
2. On Investment Summary tab, a formula that that pulls info. from the account detail tabs. (AAPL-V) (Again, Symbol names on both tabs.)  (Ex. columns G, H & I.) I also want to be able to drag the formula down when adding a new stock, at the bottom, and then sorting by Symbol.

I think I should be using VLOOKUP with INDIRECT, but have worked at it for 2 days and can't get either to work, so I'm obviously missing something.
Something like =VLOOKUP($C3,INDIRECT("'"&D$3&"'!"&"B1:E3"),3,FALSE)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand the detail of what you mean here. Can you edit your post (rather than adding a comment) and add links to images of screenshots (edited or anonymised as needed) of the summary sheet and MSTR (master?) sheet(s)

Answer (score -1):

(I think you refer "sheet" as "tab")

If one of your needs is to get the newly added or renamed MSTR sheets names dynamically, you can use **Power Query** to return all the sheets name dynamically.
You can also set auto refresh time.

Comment: Thanks for adding your comment.  I had planned on manually coping and renaming the tab's ONLY because I didn't know it could be done automatically. I've never used Power Query.  Would appreciate any suggestions on how to use it here.  Thanks.